# Unable to restrict results in SQL correctly becaue dont know all details when create Join

Tags: sql, postgresql

This problem might seem  like a very specific problem but it isn't, but Im finding it hard to use the correct terminology so Ive just described the problem Im using Postgres 9.3)

In the following sql Im trying to match an artist by name from discogs.artist table to an artist with same name in musicbrainz.artist table for the particular case of a musicbrainz.artist table containing multiple artists with the same name.

(I've already dealt with the simpler case of one musicbrainz artist matching one discogs 
artist in another query)

To do this I additionally look at the albums linked to the discogs artist and the albums linked to the musicbrainz artist and only want to return results when muscbrainz artist.id is linked to a album with same name as the releases linked to the discogs artist id as a way of getting the correct artist.

My problem is that when i join table t2 to table t3 i'm creating a set of all artists with the  same name, and restricting later by having matching album names doesn't filter out these rows so I end up with all combinations/cartesian product.

```
SELECT
t1.name,t1.id,t3.id,t5.name,t7.title
FROM discogs.artist_extra2 t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT
name
FROM musicbrainz.artist
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) AS T2
ON t1.name=t2.name
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.artist t3
ON t2.name=t3.name
INNER JOIN discogs.releases_artists t6
ON t1.id=t6.artist_id
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.artist_credit t4
on t3.name=t4.name
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.release t5
on t4.id=t5.artist_credit
INNER JOIN discogs.release t7
ON t5.name=t7.title
AND t6.release_id=t7.id;
```

Results

```
"Entity";79947;1118174;"Galactic Schematix EP";"Galactic Schematix EP"
"Entity";79947;1118174;"Tales From Abroad";"Tales From Abroad"
"Entity";79947;575594;"Galactic Schematix EP";"Galactic Schematix EP"
"Entity";79947;575594;"Tales From Abroad";"Tales From Abroad"
```

When what I want is

```
    "Entity";79947;1118174;"Galactic Schematix EP";"Galactic Schematix EP"
    "Entity";79947;575594;"Tales From Abroad";"Tales From Abroad"
```

because in fact only artist 1118174 is credited to the release "Galactic Schematix EP" and artist 575594 is credited to "Tales From Abroad"

Comment: It would be helpful if you could simplify the example and show sample data that is resulting in your output.  SQL Fiddle is also a big help.

Comment: Post the `\d table_name` output for all concerning tables.

Comment: I can do that but that going to generate alot of extra content, I thought it was fairly obvious what the issue was ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry I found it hard to explain the problem but I found the problem I needed to additionally link to artist_credit_name so I could ensure 
the artist.id linked to in t3 was the artistid used by the musicbrainz release (t5)

```
SELECT
t1.name,t1.id,t3.id,t5.name,t7.title
FROM discogs.artist_extra2 t1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT DISTINCT
name
FROM musicbrainz.artist
GROUP BY name
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
) AS T2
ON t1.name=t2.name
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.artist t3
ON t2.name=t3.name
INNER JOIN discogs.releases_artists t6
ON t1.id=t6.artist_id
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.artist_credit t4
on t3.name=t4.name
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.artist_credit_name t8
on t4.id=t8.artist_credit
INNER JOIN musicbrainz.release t5
on t4.id=t5.artist_credit
AND t3.id=t8.artist
INNER JOIN discogs.release t7
ON t5.name=t7.title
AND t6.release_id=t7.id
;
```